# Set param in url from jsp form

Tags: java, spring, jsp

i have a few questions to jsp and spring mvc..

1. I need get id value from jsp form and set in url for send request on `/request/{id}`

My jsp page:

```
<form action="/get-by-id/{id}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="id">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

and code controller for 3 question:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/change-pupil/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String changePupil(@PathVariable("id") int id, @ModelAttribute Pupil pupils){
    System.out.println(id + " " + pupils.toString());
    return "redirect:/main";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/","/main"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(){
    return "index";
}
```

how to get value from `input` and install it in the `url`?
I create method in controller which get id and send this `id` to next page and from next page send request with id in url to controller, but this method very bad

2. how move from page to page without using a controller methods?
3. How return main page without index()?

*Thanks for the help!*

Comment: Why not just add the value as model.addAttribute("value",actualValue); . Then feel free to access it in the JSP.

Comment: you talk about `id` addAttribute?